# Install LabelImg Annotation tool in Windows

Tags: python, annotations, label, labelimg

I am trying to install LabelImg in windows to make annotations of my images.I am following the steps from https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg#windows .I have installed PyQt4 and lxml.But when trying run this command:

```
pyrcc4 -o resources.py resources.qrc
```

Its giving this error:

> C:\Users\Manoj\Downloads\labelImg-master\labelImg-master>pyrcc4 -o
>   resources.py resources.qrc 'pyrcc4' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file.

and when i am trying to install using pip its giving this error:

> C:\Users\Manoj\Downloads\labelImg-master\labelImg-master>pip install
>   labelImg Collecting labelImg Using cached labelImg-1.3.4.0.tar.gz
>   Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: Traceback (most
>   recent call last): File "", line 1, in  File
>   "C:\Users\Manoj\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3ew1c3zy\labelImg\setup.
>   py", line 7, in  readme = readme_file.read() File
>   "c:\python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode return
>   codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position
>   4800: character maps to
>
> ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Manoj\Ap
>   pData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3ew1c3zy\labelImg\

Comment: I had this problem and it turned out the github page is not totally up-to date. In my case I am using Qt5 as is suggested by the project. For Qt5, you have to call pyrcc5 instead of pyrcc4.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Any reason you want to build the project rather than just download prebuilt binaries? If not, don't follow the instructions under 'Build from source' but follow the link under '[Download prebuilt binaries](http://tzutalin.github.io/labelImg/)'

Comment: The link is now broken. I found useful this link now with the Windows releases https://github.com/heartexlabs/labelImg/releases . For example, at the time of this comment, I downloaded windows_v1.8.1.zip, unzip it and then run the `labelImg.exe` file

Answer (score 3):

You have to open the e*nvironmental variable* on your computer and check if **pyrcc5** or pyrcc4 file is present in the *scripts* folder.
If not then to install the dev tools for PyQt5 use "`pip install pyqt5-dev-tools`" in case of **PyQt5**.
Then open the python path and see if pyrcc5 files must be in the scripts folder now.

Now use following commands

`pyrcc5 -o resources.py resources.qrc`

```
python labelImg.py
```

*labelImg* should be working by now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install PyQt5 first. Try this:

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

and now try running that code.